# How to test the brightness of the light bulb?

Tags: energy

I am working on the project using different kinds of wires, like copper lead silver and testing the brightness of the bulb using different wires. Can anyone please let me know how to test the bright ness of the bulb? Is there any instrument we can get to test the brightness?

Comment: a numerical analysis of a photography ? doable on a smartphone with 2 or 3 intrinsic languages to compute intensity from pixel values

Comment: Use a photodiode and a current meter.